# writeObject(this) halts the program

Tags: java, finalizer

I am learning about Garbage collection and Java Object Serialization. In my code before I included the code for serialization, 3 objects were getting finalized. Now only one finalize() is getting called and inside after creating the **FileOutputStream** object my program is halting

I have implemented java.io.Serializable in the Project class and previously when finalize() only had one println, it was getting executed perfectly, 3 objects were were getting finalized, but now it halts after the line

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(projectName + ".bin");
```

class Project :

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Project implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4721106266710903835L;
    int projectID;
    String projectName;

    public Project() {
        super();
    }

    public Project(int projectID, String projectName) {
        super();
        this.projectID = projectID;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        System.out.println("Object created : " + this.projectID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        try {
            super.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(this.projectID + " Deallocated");

        try {

            System.out.println("Test 0");
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(projectName + ".bin");
            System.out.println("Test 1");
            ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            System.out.println("Test 2");

            oout.writeObject(this);
            oout.flush();
            System.out.println("Done");

            fout.close();
            oout.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }

    }

}
```

class ProjectControl :

```
public class ProjectControl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project p = new Project(100, "ABC");
        System.out.println(p.projectID);
        System.out.println(p.projectName);

        p = null;

        Project p1 = new Project(200, "DEF");
        Project p2 = p1;

        p1 = null;
        System.out.println(p2.projectID);

        p2 = new Project(300, "GHI");
        System.out.println(new Project(400, "GHI").projectID);
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Initially `finalize()` was running 3 times each time printing

```
<<projectID>> deallocated
```

Now the programming is halting after once. Only Test 0 is getting printed once, before ever encountering the line

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(projectName + ".bin");
```

Comment: Just a suggestion out of random.. try the serialize outside the class. instead of serializing at finalize do the serialize at the next line after "new"

Comment: Did you try doing the same without `finalize()`? In general it is adviced NOT to use `finalize()`. What is more, as of Java 9, the method is `Deprecated`. And doing IO operations in it sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: You shouldn't do any of this in the finalizer, but if you absolutely must, you should certainly do it *before* calling `super.finalize()`.

Comment: Use a factory design pattern and make some aspects of `Project` immutable. Or have `Project` save itself on construction/modification. Or just save it when you want to. Even without `finalize` being fickle, you're using a very obscure approach to try and save things (setting all references to null and praying a GC cycle is called, again ignoring the intricacies of finalize).

Comment: NB The correct way to write any finalizer, if there is one, is to call `super.finalize()` in the `finally` block, and not catch exceptions from it.

Comment: There is no evidence here that `writeObject(this)` has halted anything. A more correct title would be 'finalizer is not always executed', which is practically a tautology.

Comment: Can we finally kill `finalize()` with fire? It was a bad idea, resulting in bad code and bad performance for GC (who have to keep objects alive just so it can call finalize on them and track that they are actually finalized...)

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to say what is happening, but my guess is that the JVM is exiting while your object's `finalize` method is being called.  (The `finalize()` call would be run on a daemon finalizer thread.  When the JVM detects that all non-daemon threads have terminated, it initiates the orderly shutdown procedure.)

For your scheme to work reliably, there need to be 100% bomb-proof guarantees that your `finalize` method will run *to completion* before the JVM exits.  The JVM doesn't make such guarantees.  On the contrary the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) for `finalize()` says:

> [T]here are no guarantees regarding the timing of finalization. The finalize method might be called on a finalizable object only after an indefinite delay, if at all.

and [JLS 12.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6) says:

> The Java programming language does not specify how soon a finalizer will be invoked, except to say that it will happen before the storage for the object is reused.

If you are relying on finalization to save the state of an object, you are on very shaky ground.

---

There used to be a method called `java.lang.System.runFinalizersOnExit` that might have helped ... in theory.  However it was deprecated in Java 1.2 and it was removed in Java 11.  According to the javadoc:

> This method is inherently unsafe.  It may result in finalizers being called on live objects while other threads are concurrently manipulating those objects, resulting in erratic behavior or deadlock.

So, if we take that warning at face value, the method would not give you 100% reliable persistence, and could even result in worse problems.

---

The `finalize` method and mechanism was marked as deprecated in Java 9, and is liable to be removed in a future Java release.  When that happens, it will be "the end of the road" for any application that depends on finalization.  You should take that as a big hint that you should *rethink* your strategy.

---

If despite all that I have said above, you still want a way to "just make it work" using finalizers, I don't think there is one that will be reliable.

Comment: He could try a shutdown hook, but they aren't supposed to be long-running.

Comment: Yea ... but he has the problem of finding what needs to be persisted.  I suspect that he is using finalizers in an attempt to solve that problem.  (Drop everything on the flow and let the GC trigger the persisting.)  But that won't work for this reason ... and others.

Comment: You also have to wonder why such a trivial class is being persisted at all, and why he doesn't just save the {ID,name} in a text file. One would hope there is quite a bit more to it than what is shown.

Comment: I would guess that this is a test ... to see if he can get his approach to work.